# two local frame with same domain

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Assume M is oriented smooth n-manifold, and further assume there exist two orientation $\mathcal{O_1}$ and $\mathcal{O}_2$  on the manifold. Now since M is oriented manifold has a continuous orientation,so for $p\in M$,exist a local frame on neighborhood of $p$,denoted it $((E_i),U)$ on $U$ which agree the first orientation $\mathcal{O_1}$.

And another local frame on $((E'_i),V)$ that around p and agree the second orientation $\mathcal{O}_2$ ,correct?

Now comes the question,why we can further assume the neighborhood $U$ and $V$ be the same one($U = V$) and connected?

Comment: Because $U \cap V$ is an open neighborhood of $p$, so you replace both $U$ and $V$ by $U\cap V$ and rename everything. If $U\cap V$ is not connected, you take a connected neighborhood $W \subseteq U\cap V$ of $p$ and replace everything by this $W$. Since your frames were defined on $U\cap V$, they are defined in $W$ as well. (There is nothing deep going on here and this is completely unrelated to orientations)

Comment: @Ivo Terek ,thank you,we can find such $W\subset U\bigcap V$ since coordinate ball can be the basis of $M$ correct,so always exist one connected $W$ contains in $U\bigcap V$

Comment: Yes, you can take a coordinate ball. I didn't say that explicitly because I thought you might get confused and think the associated coordinate frame (which is irrelevant here) would enter the discussion somehow.

Comment: I got it,thank you